# token expiration - How to get + 1 hour timestamp node.js

Tags: node.js, express, datetime

I'm working on user authentication. when a user signs up I want to send them a confirmation email.

I have generated the confirmation token like so.

```
const token = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('hex');
```

then I'm storing this token in my db with the expiration timestamp.

```
const d = new Date()
d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1) // expires in 1 hour
```

checking if the token is expired or not.

```
if (timestampFromDB < new Date()) {
  // token expired
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: If it works then it's at least *A* right way. It seems ok to me. Do you have any specific concerns..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const d = new Date() + (60 * 60 * 1000)` gets you a Javascript timestamp one hour in the future.

What you have with `d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1)` does *not* do what you want after 23:00 each day.

Your expiration checking is fine.